# send checkbox ngModel into filter

Tags: angular

My goal is if the user clicks a item in the hover panel, that all users get filtered and the table shows only the users who got the same item in this special category.
My current problem is that the ngModel of my chechbox dont work correctly. If i click one of the checkboxes it just returns me a true or false.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let char of allChars">
                                        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="resultModel.char" (ngModelChange)="FilterChanged()" name="allgemeinesMerkmal">
                                            {{char.bezeichnung}}
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </ng-container>
```

I already tried to pass resultModel.char.bezeichnung but then the console returns a error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bezeichnung')

So i dont know how to handle this specific checkbox values. I need the values because i want to pass the checkboxes into my filter which looks like:

```html
map( p => (!this.resultModel) ? p:p.filter(((i:any) => this.getAllgemeineMerkmaleBezeichnung(i.allgemeinesMerkmal)?.toLowerCase().includes(this.resultModel.toLowerCase())))),

//My getAllgemeineMerkmale function
 getAllgemeineMerkmaleBezeichnung(allgemeinesMerkmal: AllgemeineMerkmaleZuordnungen[]){
    return this.allChars.filter((i:any) =>  allgemeinesMerkmal.findIndex(p => p.allgemeinesMerkmalId == i.allgemeinesMerkmalId) >= 0).map((p:any) => p.bezeichnung);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for a "value"?

<mat-checkbox [value]="char.bezeichnung" [(ngModel)]="resultModel.char" (ngModelChange)="FilterChanged()" name="allgemeinesMerkmal">
{{char.bezeichnung}}

Comment: At least its a value yes, but the value of the clicked item needs to be passed through the ngModel into the filter

Comment: your [(ngModel)]="resultModel.char"  should be a local variable meaning declared in your component eg [(ngModel)]="myResultModel" then you can use variable.